# Chrome Console: Symbol - "^" meaning in javaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

When I open the Chrome console and write following i get wierd results.

```
5^5 gives 0 

5^6 gives 3

3^8 gives 11
```

Also, attached a screenshot here [image]
Does anyone have any idea?

This question is pure out of curiosity!

Comment: Bitwise exclusive-OR. [There is an online language specification that contains answers to all sorts of questions like this.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) It's also the same operator in many other C-like languages.

Comment: The Google search term for this is "mdn JavaScript operators" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Comment: Thank you @Pointy. :) You are right! It adds up now. If you move your comment to answer, i can accept it

Comment: The bitwise XOR is actually most commonly used to flip booleans, at least that's what I use it mostly for, and also where I most commonly see it, something like `var k=true; k ^= true;` which could also be written as `var k=true; k = !k;`

Comment: @adeneo You've never done low-level bit twiddling then ;)  Being able to pack 32 boolean flags into a single variable is memory efficient. :) *Though I do that more in other languages, I have done it JS too.*

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher - I have, but not very often, and I rarely need XOR, usually it's just shifting bits. However I often use the `var ^= true;` trick, and that's also where I most often see the XOR in other code.